# Extra node rendering is gone when node's title is edited

Tags: javascript, fancytree

In `renderNode` event handler I add a button to `node.span` as follows:

```
 renderNode: function (event, data) {
   var node = data.node;
   var buttons = $('<button type="button" title="info" onclick="info(\'' + node.key + '\')" class="infobtn">i</button>');
   $(node.span).append(buttons);
 }
```

The Fancytree I am using has the 'edit' extension enabled. When I edit a node title - even if I don't change the title at all - the defined button is gone.

Is there a way to keep the added button? Or should I add it again in the 'edit' extension's `save` event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *filter* and *edit* extensions reset the node's markup, so you have to re-apply your extension in the respective callbacks.

Note that release 2.18+ will introduce a new callback `enhanceTitle()` to make this easier.